# Joi validation - how to make a field optional based on input

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I've been trying to implement the following joi validation.

```
joiSchema = Joi.object().keys({
      taskno: Joi.string().alphanum().required().uppercase().trim(),
      taskstatus: Joi.valid('G', 'C', 'I', 'S'),
      taskpriority: Joi.number().integer().max(5).min(1),
      stuckreason: Joi.string().allow('').max(200).trim(),
      dttarget: Joi.date().iso(),
      dtdue: Joi.date().iso(),
      dtcomplete: Joi.when('taskstatus', {
        is: Joi.valid('C', 'I'),
        then: Joi.date().iso().required(),
      })
    });
```

My object contains taskno, dttarget and dtdue and I only want to validate this. 
If i `joi.validate()` object it returns error *"dtcomplete is required"*. 
Is there a way to optionally check *"dtcomplete"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the condition for `dtcomplete`  along with `exist()` in `Joi`

So the code will be like below

```
joiSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  taskno: Joi.string().alphanum().required().uppercase().trim(),
  taskstatus: Joi.valid('G', 'C', 'I', 'S'),
  taskpriority: Joi.number().integer().max(5).min(1),
  stuckreason: Joi.string().allow('').max(200).trim(),
  dttarget: Joi.date().iso(),
  dtdue: Joi.date().iso(),
  dtcomplete: Joi.when('taskstatus', {
    is: Joi.exist().valid('C', 'I'),
    then: Joi.date().iso().required(),
  })
});
```

Only the difference is at  `is: Joi.exist().valid('C', 'I'),`